# SQL Problem with IN keyword in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql, search

The next line returns all the ID's from the table that has those ingredients..

```
SELECT DISTINCT RecID 
FROM ingr 
WHERE Ingredient IN ('rice', 'salt', 'pepper')
```

However, if I throw that in a stored procedure, it doesn't work...

First problem was I couldn't pass ' (apostrophe) so I had to use another character which I why I replace it.

```
DECLARE @IngList nvarchar(255)
SET @IngList = replace('(|rice|,|salt|,|pepper|)','|','''')

-- select @inglist ->  Result: 'rice','salt','pepper'
SELECT DISTINCT RecID 
FROM ingr 
WHERE Ingredient IN (@IngList)
```

Result is nothing - why?

Comment: Well - the `IN` operator is expecting a **list of values** to use - however, you're just supplying a simple, single string (which contains multiple values - but it's still just a single string). Depending on what RDBMS you're using - you need *some way* of breaking up the string you pass as a parameter into a list of values for the `IN` operator - or change your stored procedure to get a list-based parameter to begin with. But this is all **very dependent** on what **concrete RDBMS** you're using - `SQL` is just the query language, that doesn't tell us what you're using, really ....

Comment: I'm using MSSQL latest version.

Comment: Then either use `STRING_SPLIT` on your string parameter, or check out [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to pass in multiple values (suitable for `IN`)

Comment: Apparently not smart enough to figure it out, so I'll just create a dynamic query...

Answer (score 1):

You are far better off using a table variable, temp table or table-valued parameter. This way, you are doing a fully set-based operation

```sql
DECLARE @IngList TABLE (Ingredient nvarchar(255) NOT NULL);

INSERT @IngList (Ingredient)
VALUES ('rice'), ('salt'), ('pepper');

SELECT DISTINCT RecID 
FROM ingr 
WHERE Ingredient IN (SELECT t.Ingredient FROM @IngList t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a delimited list of values in a string, you can use `string_split` to extract them as a derived table. you can then join to it, or use it with `in`

Both the following are essentially the same:

```
select distinct RecID 
from ingr 
where Ingredient in (select value from String_Split(@IngList,','))

select distinct RecID 
from ingr 
cross apply String_Split(@IngList,',')s 
where ingredient=s.value
```